# Viewer Extension Network Calls Timing Out

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

[image]

I just wanted to check and see if anyone knows what is happening here...

Sometimes these min.js files time out at 10 seconds and throw a 504. This has happened at work and at home, wired and on wireless. It also seems to be random which library/libraries this happens to.

I'm assuming these are called to load automatically when I include the viewer3d file?
`<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the troubles. Apparently the https://developer.api.autodesk.com servers were getting some unusually heavy traffic, and our logs are showing that during that time there were a couple of long latency requests. The engineering team is currently investigating that.

Comment: Ok good to know thanks! Wasn't sure if it was something I did or not.